# How to set http header for all requests being loaded in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, user-agent, nsurlrequest

I tried the following :

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSLog([request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]);    

    if ([[request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"] isEqualToString:@"CustomName"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        NSMutableURLRequest *mutable_request= [request mutableCopy];
        [mutable_request setValue:@"CustomName" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
        request = [mutable_request copy];
        [self.web loadRequest:request];
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I even added the following lines of code to viewDidLoad() method :

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"CustomName",@"User-Agent", nil];  
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dict];
```

However whenever I try to load a request using `[self.web loadRequest:request]` it enters an infinite loop and the value for HTTPHeaderField "User-Agent" is always printed as

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_10_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B411"
```

instead of "CustomName".

Comment: The reason for infinite loop is that the header isn't being set to the value I want to, so every time the function is calling itself and is entering the else block

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@" web url to load : %@",urlToLoad);
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToLoad];
    [requestObj setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Safari/528.16", [requestObj valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
    requestObj.timeoutInterval = 120;//Request Timeout interval added for request
    [requestObj setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];//added for removing cache data of webView
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: thanks, but I think the it should be "UserAgent" instead of "User-Agent" , and in some cases I think it works if it is "User_Agent" , don't know why but it works

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I had to replace the HTTPHeader "User-Agent" to "UserAgent".
Removing the hyphen (-) did the thing for me.

Adding following method to my AppDelegate.h also worked

```
+ (void)initialize {
NSDictionary *dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"CustomName", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
```

}